# Parsing AM/PM time string to TimeSpan

Tags: c#, parsing, timespan

I'm using the following to parse a time string to a TimeSpan:

```
string[] formats = { "hhmm", "hmm", @"hh\:mm", @"h\:mm\:ss", @"h\:mm", "hh:mm tt" };

parseSuccess = TimeSpan.TryParseExact(value, formats, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, TimeSpanStyles.None, out dtValue);
```

This returns false when I try to parse a value like 9:00 AM, 5:00 PM. What is wrong here?

Comment: I would consider "9:00 AM" a **point** in time, and not a time **span**. Btw, what programming language is that? C#?

Comment: Yes, sorry it's C#

Comment: @qqilihq: The problem comes from `DateTime.TimeOfDay` in .NET returning a `TimeSpan`. The built-in date/time API is somewhat problematic, IMO...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`tt` doesn't exist as one of the format specifiers for [custom `TimeSpan` format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings). That makes sense in that `TimeSpan` is really meant to be a duration, not a time-of-day value - it's unfortunate that `DateTime.TimeOfDay` *does* return a `TimeSpan`.

It's probably simplest to parse the value as a `DateTime` and then get the time of day from that:

```
string text = "5:00 PM";
string[] formats = { "hhmm", "hmm", @"hh\:mm", @"h\:mm\:ss", @"h:mm", @"h:mm tt" };

var success = DateTime.TryParseExact(text, formats, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.None, out var value);
Console.WriteLine(value.TimeOfDay);
```

Note that I've corrected the `hh:mm tt` to `h:mm tt` as your sample data isn't 0-padded. You quite possibly want `HHmm`, and `HH:mm` instead of `hhmm` and `hh:mm` as well, to accept values like "21:00".

Alternatively, use my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library that has a specific type for time-of-day (`LocalTime`) that can be parsed directly with a `LocalTimePattern` :)

Comment: This pretty much works for all my time formats, but I'm seeing a weird issue that the PM time formats fail. For example, 4:00 AM is accepted by 2:00 PM or 5:00 PM is fail.

Comment: @devC with the *exact* code I provided? Note that with the formats accepting 'tt' you need 'h' rather than 'H'. It should be fine, as per my example code.

Comment: I see. I still had H in my format array. Thanks a heap!!